# How to Recolor Paragraph

Tags: html

I am trying to write the paragraph in the color red, but I am not getting the result i expected, can someone help me?

```html
<h1> OluwaTomyin Giwa is an awesome guy. </h1>
    <br>
    <p color="red" no shade>  OluwaTomiyin was born in Nigeria in the year 1984, to the parents of John and Olufunto Giwa. </p>
```

Comment: Here let me google it for you https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp

Comment: The `<p>` tag has never supported a `color` attribute.

Comment: @OneShadow [MDN is the better result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/What_is_CSS).

Answer (score 0):

You should write it as

```css
<p> <span style="color:red;"> Your Text</span</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use style.

```html
<h1> OluwaTomyin Giwa is an awesome guy. </h1>
<br>
<p style="color:red;" no shade>  OluwaTomiyin was born in Nigeria in the year 1984, to the parents of John and Olufunto Giwa. </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` tag don't have `color` attribute
Use inline CSS to do so...

```
<h1> OluwaTomyin Giwa is an awesome guy. </h1>
<br>
<p style="color:red;" no shade>  OluwaTomiyin was born in Nigeria in the year 1984, to the parents of John and Olufunto Giwa. </p>
```

Or you can use internal CSS

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.red {
color:red;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1> OluwaTomyin Giwa is an awesome guy. </h1>
    <br>
    <p class="red" no shade>  OluwaTomiyin was born in Nigeria in the year 1984, to the parents of John and Olufunto Giwa. </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```